# New method in a model or new service - which approach is better?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a new app with following business process:

1. User fill in a registration form.
2. Once registration form is being saved, a new Training Company is created
3. User get an e-mail with a pdf with his registration form and unique url
4. User uses unique url to attach signed registration form Admin can accept or reject

What is the best approach to Training Company creation?

First solution: new service that creates a TrainingCompany

```
class TrainingCompanyService

  def initialize(company_name)
    @name = company_name
  end

  def create_new_training_company
    TrainingCompany.new(company_name: @name).save
  end

end
```

create action in RegistrationFormController:

```
def create
    @registration_form = RegistrationForm.new(registration_form_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration_form.save
        format.html { redirect_to @registration_form, notice: 'Registration form was successfully created.' }
        TrainingCompanyService.new(@registration_form.company_name).create_new_training_company
        RegistrationFormMailer.with(registration_form: @registration_form).after_registration_email.deliver_later
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Second solution: new method inside TrainingCompany model:

```
class RegistrationForm < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :training_company, optional: true
  has_one_attached :registration_form

  has_secure_token :signed_form_upload_token


  def create_new_training_company
    TrainingCompany.new(company_name: self.company_name, registration_form_id: self.id).save
  end
end
```

create action in RegistrationFormController:

```
def create
    @registration_form = RegistrationForm.new(registration_form_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration_form.save && @registration_form.create_new_training_company
        format.html { redirect_to @registration_form, notice: 'Registration form was successfully created.' }

        RegistrationFormMailer.with(registration_form: @registration_form).after_registration_email.deliver_later
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
 end
```

Which solution would you choose and why? Personally i prefer the second one (new method inside the model)...

Comment: Why do you prefer the second one?

Comment: I think that keeping all info and actions that are related to a model inside the model is a good idea. Of course if system will grow, sooner or later there might be a need to create some services.... But to be honest - i am not sure if my approach is good... any suggestions or tips?

Comment: Personally, I try to (1) keep *everything* skinny, (2) limit models to their own data operations, and (3) limit the amount any one thing knows about any other things. As such, I make extensive use of services and other plain old ruby objects like managers, presenters, and decorators.

Comment: jvillian - it seems reasonable...While you are writing a service - you do 1 service per operation (i.e.). CreateNewTrainingCompanyService, or one service per model (i.e. TrainingCompanyService) with multiple public methods (i.e. Create, update, etc)

Comment: My services only ever have one public class method, `call`. So, the former, I suppose.